# ZF2 & Doctrine2: mock EntityRepository::findOneByField

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

Is it possible to mock the

```
EntityRepository::findOneBy{$field}($value)
```

function?

Using:

```
->getMock('EntityRepository')
->expects($this->any())
->method('findOneByField')
```

resolves always in null, as `findOneByField` isn't a real function but gets mapped by `__call()`. At least I think that that is the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock the `__call` method. Will give a simple example:

*Class:*

```
class A { 

    public function __call($fname, $args) {
        if($fname === 'test') {
            return 'test';
        }   
    }   
}
```

*Test:*

```
class ATest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testA() {:
        $mock = $this->getMock('A');

        $mock->expects($this->any())
            ->method('__call')
            ->with('test')
            ->will($this->returnValue('test'));

        var_dump($mock->test());
    }   
}
```

You can do the same with the `EntityRepository`. I just hadn't one by the hand for testing.